# Pyramid routing issue

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to setup a json service with a dynamic route: /action/{id}

I get a 404 when I navigate to: http://example.com:8080/action/test

Based on [this documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/examples.html), it seems like my routing is configured correctly, but it is not.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(route_name="action", renderer="json")
def run_action(self):
    id = self.request.matchdict['id']
    return {'id': id}


def main():
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('action', '/action/{id}')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = main()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a call to config.scan() in your main() function:

```
def main():
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('action', '/action/{id}')
    config.scan()
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    return app
```

The @view_config decorator doesn't do anything on its own. You must call config.scan(), which will then go and look for all @view_config declarations that have a route_name matching one of config's routes:

```
config.add_route('foo')
config.scan()
```

will detect:

```
@view_config(route_name="foo")
```

Also, if you're going to have run_action as a standalone function (and not a class method), it should accept a single argument, 'request' (not 'self' as in your excerpt):

```
@view_config(route_name="action", renderer="json")
def run_action(request):
    id = request.matchdict['id']
    return {'id': id}
```

If you do plan on having run_action as a class method, you need to initialize that class correctly, and decorate just the class method:

```
class MyArbitraryClass():
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name="action", renderer="json")
    def run_action(self):
        id = request.matchdict['id']
        return {'id': id}
```

Comment: It's not directly related to the OP's question so I'll just leave this as a comment. I was having 404 trouble in my Pyramid app. The `config.scan` calls and the `@view_config` decorators were all in place. My problem was, apparently, I have two methods with the same name having different `@view_config` decorations.

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid Documentation:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html

## views.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(route_name="action", renderer="json")
def run_action(request):
    id = request.matchdict['id']
    return {'id': id}


def main():
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('action', '/action/{id}')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    return app
```

## _ *init*_.py

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_route('action', '/action/{id}')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```